# Показать оригинал по клику

Tags: javascript, html

Перерыл Гугл, либо громоздкое с 100500 стилей, которые дублируют мои, либо вообще не работают.

Надо по клику миниатюры, открыть оригинал.

```
<a href="orig.jpeg"><img src="small.jpeg"></a>
```

В JS не силен.

Может что посоветует кто)

Comment: открыть в каком смысле? если просто открыть картинку в окне, то ваш код вроде как рабочий

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите открыть картинку как элемент, то как вариант на  JS:

```js
let flag=true;
document.querySelector('.small').onclick=()=>{
  document.querySelector('.original').style.display=(flag)?'block':'none';
  flag=!flag;
}
```

```css
img.small{
  cursor:pointer;
}
img.original{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<img class="small" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/6985c2/000000.png&amp;text=%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%A2%D0%98%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%A7%D0%9A%D0%90" alt="" />
<img class="original" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/6985c2/000000.png&amp;text=%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%A2%D0%98%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%A9%D0%95" alt="" />
```

А вот вариант для тех, кому интересно без JS - https://codepen.io/qwerty_wasd/pen/PaMOYZ

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
}


/*стили выше добавлены только для этого примера, в реальном проекте используйте normilize.css\reset.css*/

.midget-module {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

label.midget-close {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label.midget-close:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

label.midget-open {}

.mid-original {
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mid-original>img {
  margin: auto;
}

input#midget {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

input#midget:checked~.mid-original {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="midget-module">
  <label class="midget-open" for="midget">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/6985c2/000000.png&amp;text=%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%A2%D0%98%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%A7%D0%9A%D0%90" alt=""/>
  </label>
  <input id="midget" type="checkbox" />
  <div class="mid-original">
    <label class="midget-close" for="midget">&#10008;</label>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/6985c2/000000.png&amp;text=%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%A2%D0%98%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%A9%D0%95" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```